# Обработка событий. Связать radiobutton с button

Tags: javascript, button, события, radio

У меня есть форма в ней в зависимости от выбора радио кнопки вычисляется площадь. Как связать радиокнопку с кнопкой? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/badmmstar/6nLse3tc/)

```
<form action="areaOfFigure.js">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2>Вычисление площади треугольника</h2>
                    <label for="aSide">Введите сторону a: <input type="text" name="aSide" id="aSide" /></label>
                    <label for="bSide">Введите сторону b: <input type="text" name="bSide" id="bSide" /></label>
                    <label for="cSide">Введите сторону c: <input type="text" name="cSide" id="cSide" /></label>
                    <label><input onchange="" id="triangle" type="radio" name="radio-buttons" value="1">Площадь треугольника</label>
                </div>
                <label for="outPut">Вывод: <input type="text" name="outPut" id="outPut" /></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2>Вычисление площади трапеции</h2>
                    <label for="aBase">Введите основу a: <input type="text" name="aBase" id="aBase" /></label>
                    <label for="bBase">Введите основу b: <input type="text" name="bBase" id="bBase" /></label>
                    <label for="hHeight">Введите высоту h: <input type="text" name="hHeight" id="hHeight" /></label>
                    <div><label><input onchange="" id="trapezium" type="radio" name="radio-buttons" value="2">Площадь трапеции</label></div>
                </div>
                <label for="outPut">Вывод: <input type="text" name="outPut" id="outPut" /></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2>Вычисление площади круга по диаметру</h2>
                    <label for="Ddiameter">Введите D (внешний диаметр кольца): <input type="text" name="Ddiameter" id="Ddiameter" /></label>
                    <label for="ddiameter">Введите d (внутренний диаметр кольца): <input type="text" name="ddiameter" id="ddiameter" /></label>
                    <div><label><input onchange="" id="ring" type="radio" name="radio-buttons" value="3" />Площадь круга</label></div>
                </div>
                <label for="outPut">Вывод: <input type="text" name="outPut" id="outPut" /></label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="center"><input onclick="" type="button" name="Solution" id="solution" class="btn btn-outline-success" value="solution" /></div>
    </form>
```

```js
'use strict'

function calculateAreaTriangle() {
  a = document.getElementById("aSide");
  b = document.getElementById("bSide");
  c = document.getElementById("cSide");
  p = (a + b + c) / 2;
  s = Math.sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c))
  document.getElementById("outPut") = s;
}

function calculateAreaTrapezium() {
  a = document.getElementById("aBase");
  b = document.getElementById("bBase");
  h = document.getElementById("hHeight");
  s = ((a + b) / 2) * h;
  document.getElementById("outPut") = s;
}

function calculateAreaRing() {
  D = document.getElementById("Ddiameter");
  d = document.getElementById("ddiameter");
  s = (Math.PI * (D * D - d * d) / 4);
  document.getElementById("outPut") = s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше наверное поменять radio на checkbox (чтобы можно было его убрать) и в каждой функции делать проверку на "checked" и в зависимости от состояния производить действия

```
function calculateAreaTriangle() {
    if(document.getElementById("myCheck").checked){
        ...
    }else{
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: или так: 
var b = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        if(b[0].checked){
          calculateAreaTriangle();
        }else if(b[1].checked){
          calculateAreaTrapezium();
        }else if(b[2].checked){
          calculateAreaRing();
        }

Comment: Да, но всё равно нужно будет делать проверку нажат check или radio и после нажатия button выводить ответ